# Can not perform a class transition in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why can not I perform a class transition in d3.js?

`main.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>d3 playing around</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <!-- <script src="d3LibV5Min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="drawRegion">

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.css`:

```
#drawRegion {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#drawRegion .mainSvg {
    border: 2px #000 solid;
    background: #ddd953;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#drawRegion .mainSvg .blackCircle {
    border: 2px #fff solid;
    background: #000;
}

#drawRegion .mainSvg .whiteCircle {
    border: 2px #000 solid;
    background: #fff;
}
```

`main.js`:

```
var drawRegion = d3.select("#drawRegion");

var svg = drawRegion
    .append("svg")
    .classed("mainSvg", true);

var circle = svg
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 250)
    .attr("cy", 250)
    .attr("r", 50)
    .classed("blackCircle", true);

var tr = d3
    .transition()
    .duration(5000);
circle
    .transition(tr)
    .classed("blackCircle", false)
    .classed("whiteCircle", true);
```

What I expect from this code to do is to show a black circle with a white border and transition into a white circle with a black border gradually after 5 seconds. But that just does not happen. I am learning the `d3.js` over [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_animation.htm) and according to the tutorial I am doing everything correctly.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4jtsdszr/) is the fiddle. Will be grateful for any help provided here.

I know other approaches like, for example, using the `css-transitions`, but I would like to feel the power of `d3.js` since I decided to learn it profoundly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you are trying to do this:

```
circle.classed("blackCircle",true);

circle.transition()
  .classed("blackCircle",false);
  .classed("whiteCircle",true);
```

The issue is that a transition doesn't offer a `classed` method. If you look at the error message you get, you can confirm this: `circle.transition(...).classed is not a function`.
(See [the docs for available methods](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#modifying-elements))
 A d3 transition interpolates between a starting value and an end value - and as a boolean value is either true or false, it is hard to transition between these two points using only those two values. Hence, `classed` cannot be a method of a d3 transition in its current form.

If you would like this to work with d3, you could abandon the class approach and apply styles directly using `selection.style()` and `transition.style()`.

For example:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",100)
  .attr("cy",50)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill","steelblue");
  
var t = d3.transition()
  .duration(3000);
  
circle.transition(t)
  .style("fill","orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'll also add that something like:

```
circle.attr("class","whiteCircle");

circle.transition().attr("class","blackCircle");
```

Won't work as well, despite .attr() being a method of d3.transition(). This is because the interpolator will attempt to interpolate the string values between start and end using [d3.interpolateString](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateString). Given two strings without numbers, the second value will be used at all points on the transition (See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7z5ycc4/)).

*Also, you use background as a css property for the svg circle, you need to use fill when working with svg elements. Likewise, instead of border you need to use stroke, stroke-width, etc*