# Tooltips not working on the initial plot but start working once the plot changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a strange problem; I have tooltips (with [`d3-tip`](https://github.com/caged/d3-tip)) in d3, working on a scatter plot. They don't work at all on the initial plot. Mouseover events aren't even working; I have a console log for these.

The scatter plot has three sets of data on each axis. When I choose another set of data, the tooltips start working.

When I go back to the original data, the tooltips also work. The website is published here if someone can take a look: https://sean-galloway.github.io/D3-Challenge/.

I set the tooltip like this:

```
// Set up the tool tip
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([-8, 0])
    .html(d => `<strong>${d.state}</strong><br>${optionListXTitle[optionX]}: ${d[optionListX[optionX]]}<br>${optionListYTitle[optionY]}: ${d[optionListY[optionY]]}`);

// Link the tool tip to the chart
chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans").call(tool_tip);

// Set up the listeners
chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans")
        .on("mousemove", function (d) { console.log(`d: ${JSON.stringify(d)}`); tool_tip.show(d, this);})
        .on("mouseover", function (d) { console.log(`d: ${JSON.stringify(d)}`); tool_tip.show(d, this);})
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { tool_tip.hide(d);});c
```

I've gone thru all of the recommendations, and nothing seems to work.

Why do the tooltips fail on the first post but work once it changes?

Note: I got this working with the recommendation of a few folks to reorder the code. Here is the working section:

```
// Add all of the new circles
transCircles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans")
    .transition(t)
    .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
    .attr("cy", y(0))
```

Basically, the attr("class") for each declaration was put above the transition.

Comment: Please post code block you've tried.

Comment: I took a brief look at the code. Try moving the `.attr("class", "stateCircleTrans")` to before the `.transition(t)`. If this was the issue let me know so I can elaborate in the answer. Without reproducing the error it is only a guess, please consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is the issue; I'm just curious why does this works? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I got the answer from the link @Robin Mackenzie provided. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Although @RobinMackenzie answered with the working example, I added another answer to explain the difference between the selection object and the transition object, and why the issue was happening only at the first render.

Answer (score 2):

As we discussed in the comments earlier, the issue is that the class is being declared after a transition:

```
    // Add all of the new circles
    transCircles.enter().append("circle").transition(t)
    ...
    .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans")
```

This happens because a "selection" object becomes a "transition" object at the point that the transition is introduced. A transition object is slightly different than a selection because the declared attributes only reach their defined value after the transition ends. During the transition, the attribute is in an interpolation state and changes constantly to create the animation.

When the class is declared after the transition, D3 tries to interpolate `undefined` (because no class was never defined) into `'stateCircleTrans'` (the target of the transition). Although there is no interpolation supported between undefined and a string, D3 does perform the change in the transition; it is just not smooth.

This is why the bug only happens in the first render. At that point, the transition didn't have time to execute, and the class still is `undefined` when the following line is executed for the first time:

```
    // Link the tool tip to the chart
    chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans").call(tool_tip);
```

The selection is empty because there are no `".stateCircleTrans"` (yet!).

In subsequent runs, D3 already finished the transition, and the state never goes back to `undefined,`. This means the transition will try to interpolate `".stateCircleTrans"` to `".stateCircleTrans"`, which is trivial and do not change the class anymore, making the `".stateCircleTrans"` selection valid for the rest of the program.

This issue can be avoided by declaring the class in the selection object, as opposed to the transition:

```
    // Add all of the new circles
    transCircles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans").transition(t)
    ...
```

Which immediately applies the 'stateCircleTrans' class to the circles, making the d3-tip call always valid from the start.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.js` file here:

```
// Add all of the new circles
transCircles.enter().append("circle").transition(t)
    .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
    .attr("cy", y(0))
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
    .transition(t)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
    .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));
```

Change to:

```
// Add all of the new circles
transCircles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans") // <---- class the element before the transition
    .transition(t)
    .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
    .attr("cy", y(0))
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
    .transition(t)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
    .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));
```

@RodrigoDivino is correct in his comment. Note you don't get any sort of error and just unexpected behaviour because [`transition` takes an `attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attr) but does not expect a `class` assignment so I guess it is failing gracefully. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552766/can-not-perform-a-class-transition-in-d3-js) as well.

Working example:

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Global Options
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var optionListX = ["poverty", "age", "income"];
var optionX = 0;
var optionListY = ["healthcare", "smokes", "obesity"]
var optionY = 0;
var healthData = [];
var optionListXTitle = ["Poverty", "Age", "Income"];
var optionListYTitle = ["Health Care", "Smokes", "Obesity"];
var circleRadius = 14;
var abbrFontSize = "14px";
var abbrYoffset = 4;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set width and height parameters to be used in the canvas
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var svgWidth = 900;
var svgHeight = 600;

// Set svg margins
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 90
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create the width and height based svg margins and parameters to fit chart group within the canvas
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Create the canvas to append the SVG group that contains the states data
// Give the canvas width and height calling the variables predefined.
var svg = d3.select("#scatter").append("svg").attr("width", svgWidth).attr("height", svgHeight);

// Create the chartGroup that will contain the data
// Use transform attribute to fit it within the canvas
var chartGroup = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`).attr("pointer-events", "stroke");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scales and Axes
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x)
var xAxis = chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")");

var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y)
var yAxis = chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Labels
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var xAxisLabels = [];
xAxisLabels.push(xAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ", 0)")
            .attr("y", 30)
            .text("In Poverty (%)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionX = 0; updateChart();}));
xAxisLabels.push(xAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ", 0)")
            .attr("y", 50)
            .text("Age (Median)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionX = 1; updateChart();}));
xAxisLabels.push(xAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ", 0)")
            .attr("y", 70)
            .text("Household Income (Median)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionX = 2; updateChart();}));

var yAxisLabels = [];
yAxisLabels.push(yAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("id", optionListY[0])
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", -height/2)
            .attr("y", -margin.left + 60)
            .text("Lacks Health Care (%)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionY = 0; updateChart();}));
yAxisLabels.push(yAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("id", optionListY[1])
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", -height/2)
            .attr("y", -margin.left + 40)
            .text("Smokes (%)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionY = 1; updateChart();}));
yAxisLabels.push(yAxis.append("text")
            .attr("class", "inactive")
            .attr("id", optionListY[2])
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", -height/2)
            .attr("y", -margin.left + 20)
            .text("Obese (%)")
            .on("click", function (d) { optionY = 2; updateChart();}));

let chartTitles = [
                    ["Poverty versus Lacks Health Care", "Poverty versus Smokes", "Poverty versus Obesity"],
                    ["Age versus Lacks Health Care", "Age versus Smokes", "Age versus Obesity"],
                    ["Household Income versus Lacks Health Care", "Household Income versus Smokes", "Household Income versus Obesity"]
                ];
let chartCommentary = [
                        ["There is a correlation between Poverty and Health care. As Poverty increases, one is more likely to Lack Health Care",
                            "There is a correlation between Poverty and Smoking. As Poverty increases, one is more likely to Smoke",
                            "There is a correlation between Poverty and Obesity. As Poverty increases, one is more likely to be Obese"],
                        ["There is a correlation between Age and Health Care. As Age decreases, one is more likely to Lack Health Care",
                            "There is a correlation between Age and Smoking. As Age increases, one is more likely to Smoke",
                            "There is a small correlation between Age and Obesity. As Age increases, one is more likely to be Obese"],
                        ["There is a small correlation between Household Income and Lacks Health Care. As Household Income decreases, one is more likely to Lack Health Care",
                            "There is a correlation between Household Income and Smoking. As Household Income increases, one is less likely to Smoke",
                            "There is a correlation between Household Income and Obesity. As Household Income increases, one is less likely to be Obese"]
                    ];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to update the chart
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function updateChart() {
    // Standard transition for our visualization
    var t = d3.transition().duration(750);

    console.log(`updateChart X: ${optionX} : ${optionListX[optionX]}`);
    console.log(`updateChart Y: ${optionY} : ${optionListY[optionY]}`);

    // Do the Linear Regression Line First
    var xReg = healthData.map(item => item[optionListX[optionX]]);
    var yReg = healthData.map(item => item[optionListY[optionY]]);
    var [result_values_x, result_values_y, m, b, regLine] =  findLineByLeastSquares(xReg, yReg);

    // Create the Line Generators
    var lineGenerator = d3.line()
                    .x(d => x(d.x))
                    .y(d => y(d.y));
    // This if for the zero transition line
    var lineGeneratorZeroY = d3.line()
                    .x(d => x(d.x))
                    .y(d => y(0));

    var myEquation = d3.select("#equation");
    myEquation.text(`Linear Regression Equation: y = ${m.toFixed(4)}x + ${b.toFixed(4)}`);

    // Update the css for the axis's that are selected, turn all inactive first
    xAxisLabels.forEach(item => item.attr("class", "inactive"));
    yAxisLabels.forEach(item => item.attr("class", "inactive"));
    xAxisLabels[optionX].attr("class", "active");
    yAxisLabels[optionY].attr("class", "active");

    // Update the scales
    x.domain([  d3.min(healthData, d => d[optionListX[optionX]]) / 1.05,
                d3.max(healthData, d => d[optionListX[optionX]]) * 1.05])
    y.domain([  d3.min(healthData, d => d[optionListY[optionY]]) / 1.05,
                d3.max(healthData, d => d[optionListY[optionY]]) * 1.05])

    // Update the axes
    xAxis.transition(t).call(xAxisCall);
    yAxis.transition(t).call(yAxisCall);

    // update the lines
    var regressionLine = chartGroup.selectAll(".regression").data(regLine);

    // remove the unused lines
    regressionLine.exit().transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .attr("y", y(0))
        .remove();

    // Update the x/y for the remaining lines
    regressionLine.transition(t).attr("d", lineGenerator(regLine))

    // Add all of the new lines
    regressionLine.enter().append("path").transition(t)
        .attr("class", "regression")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .attr("d", lineGeneratorZeroY(regLine))
        .transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("d", lineGenerator(regLine));

    // Update the circles
    var circles = chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircle").data(healthData);

    // remove the unused circles
    circles.exit().transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .attr("cy", y(0))
        .remove();

    // Update the cx/cy for the remaining circles
    circles.transition(t)
        .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));

    // Add all of the new circles
    circles.enter().append("circle").transition(t)
        .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("cy", y(0))
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .attr("class", "stateCircle")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));
    
    // Update the text abbreviations
    var abbrevs = chartGroup.selectAll(".stateText").data(healthData);

    // remove the unused text
    abbrevs.exit().transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .attr("y", y(0))
        .remove()

    // Update the x/y for the remaining text
    abbrevs.transition(t)
        .attr("x", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("y", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]) + abbrYoffset);

    // Add all of the new text
    abbrevs.enter().append("text").transition(t)
        .attr("x", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("y", y(0))
        .attr("class", "stateText")
        .style("font-size", abbrFontSize)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
        .text(d => d.abbr)
        .transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("y", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]) + abbrYoffset );

    // Update the transparent circles; these are needed so the tooltips work cleanly
    var transCircles = chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans")
        .data(healthData);

    // Created transparent circles to go on top so tool tips aren't so flaky
    // remove the unused circles
    transCircles.exit().transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
        .attr("cy", y(0))
        .remove();

    // Update the cx/cy for the remaining circles
    transCircles.transition(t)
        .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));

    // Add all of the new circles
    transCircles.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "stateCircleTrans")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("cx", d => x(d[optionListX[optionX]]))
        .attr("cy", y(0))
        .attr("r", circleRadius)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
        .transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0)
        .attr("cy", d => y(d[optionListY[optionY]]));
        
console.log(`Number of elements classed stateCircleTrans: ${chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans").size()}`);

    // Set up the tool tip
    var tool_tip = d3.tip()
        .attr("class", "d3-tip")
        .offset([-8, 0])
        .html(d => `<strong>${d.state}</strong><br>${optionListXTitle[optionX]}: ${d[optionListX[optionX]]}<br>${optionListYTitle[optionY]}: ${d[optionListY[optionY]]}`);

    // Link the tool tip to the chart
    chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans").call(tool_tip);

    // Set up the listeners
    chartGroup.selectAll(".stateCircleTrans")
            .on("mousemove", function (d) { console.log(`d: ${JSON.stringify(d)}`); tool_tip.show(d, this);})
            .on("mouseover", function (d) { console.log(`d: ${JSON.stringify(d)}`); tool_tip.show(d, this);})
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { tool_tip.hide(d);});

    // Update the Commentary
    var myHeader = d3.select("#healthHeader");
    myHeader.text(chartTitles[optionX][optionY]);

    var myCommentary = d3.select("#healthCommentary");
    myCommentary.text(chartCommentary[optionX][optionY]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Import Data
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//var file = "assets/data/data.csv"

// Function is called and passes csv data
//d3.csv(file).then(successHandle, errorHandle);

// Use error handling function to append data and SVG objects
// If error exist it will be only visible in console
//function errorHandle(error) {
//    throw err;
//}

// Function takes in argument statesData
//function successHandle(data) {

    // Assign the local data to the global healthData
    healthData = data();

    // Cast the value to a number for each piece of healthData
    healthData.map(function (element) {
        element.poverty = +element.poverty;
        element.age = +element.age;
        element.income = +element.income;
        element.healthcare = +element.healthcare;
        element.smokes = +element.smokes;
        element.obesity = +element.obesity;
    });

    updateChart();
//};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Linear Regression Function
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function findLineByLeastSquares(values_x, values_y) {
    var x_sum = 0;
    var y_sum = 0;
    var xy_sum = 0;
    var xx_sum = 0;
    var count = 0;

     // The above is just for quick access, makes the program faster
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var values_length = values_x.length;

    if (values_length != values_y.length) {
        throw new Error('The parameters values_x and values_y need to have same size!');
    }

     // Above and below cover edge cases
    if (values_length === 0) {
        return [ [], [] ];
    }

    // Calculate the sum for each of the parts necessary.
    for (let i = 0; i < values_length; i++) {
        x = values_x[i];
        y = values_y[i];
        x_sum+= x;
        y_sum+= y;
        xx_sum += x*x;
        xy_sum += x*y;
        count++;
    }

    // Calculate m and b for the line equation:
    // y = x * m + b
    var m = (count*xy_sum - x_sum*y_sum) / (count*xx_sum - x_sum*x_sum);
    var b = (y_sum/count) - (m*x_sum)/count;

    // We then return the x and y data points according to our fit
    var result_values_x = [];
    var result_values_y = [];
    var values_x_sort = values_x.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    // console.log(`values_x: ${values_x}`);
    // console.log(`values_x_sort: ${values_x_sort}`);
    for (let i = 0; i < values_length; i++) {
        x = values_x_sort[i];
        y = x * m + b;
        result_values_x.push(x);
        result_values_y.push(y);
    }

    var regLineFull = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result_values_x.length; i++) {
        regLineFull.push({x: result_values_x[i], y: result_values_y[i]});
    }

    var regLine = [];
    regLine.push(regLineFull[0]);
    regLine.push(regLineFull[regLineFull.length-1]);

    return [result_values_x, result_values_y, m, b, regLine];
}

function data() {
  const src = {
    "headers": ["id", "state", "abbr", "poverty", "povertyMoe", "age", "ageMoe", "income", "incomeMoe", "healthcare", "healthcareLow", "healthcareHigh", "obesity", "obesityLow", "obesityHigh", "smokes", "smokesLow", "smokesHigh"], 
    "rows": [
      [1, "Alabama", "AL", 19.3, 0.5, 38.6, 0.2, 42830, 598, 13.9, 12.7, 15.1, 33.5, 32.1, 35, 21.1, 19.8, 22.5], 
      [2, "Alaska", "AK", 11.2, 0.9, 33.3, 0.3, 71583, 1784, 15, 13.3, 16.6, 29.7, 27.8, 31.6, 19.9, 18.2, 21.6], 
      [4, "Arizona", "AZ", 18.2, 0.4, 36.9, 0.1, 50068, 483, 14.4, 13.3, 15.6, 28.9, 27.7, 30.2, 16.5, 15.4, 17.6], 
      [5, "Arkansas", "AR", 18.9, 0.5, 37.8, 0.2, 41262, 653, 16.3, 14.4, 18.2, 35.9, 33.8, 38, 24.7, 22.7, 26.7], 
      [6, "California", "CA", 16.4, 0.2, 36, 0.1, 61933, 238, 14.8, 13.8, 15.8, 24.7, 23.5, 25.9, 12.9, 11.9, 13.8], 
      [8, "Colorado", "CO", 12, 0.4, 36.3, 0.1, 61303, 487, 12.8, 11.9, 13.6, 21.3, 20.4, 22.2, 15.7, 14.8, 16.6], 
      [9, "Connecticut", "CT", 10.8, 0.5, 40.5, 0.2, 70048, 828, 8.7, 7.6, 9.7, 26.3, 24.8, 27.7, 15.4, 14.2, 16.7], 
      [10, "Delaware", "DE", 12.5, 0.9, 39.6, 0.3, 59716, 1674, 8.7, 7.4, 9.9, 30.7, 28.6, 32.7, 19.9, 17.9, 21.8], 
      [11, "Washington D.C.", "DC", 17.7, 1.2, 33.8, 0.2, 71648, 1996, 8.3, 6.3, 10.3, 21.7, 19.5, 23.9, 16.4, 14.2, 18.6], 
      [12, "Florida", "FL", 16.5, 0.3, 41.6, 0.1, 47463, 329, 17.6, 16.4, 18.8, 26.2, 25, 27.5, 17.7, 16.5, 18.8], 
      [13, "Georgia", "GA", 18.3, 0.4, 36.1, 0.1, 49321, 543, 20.9, 19.3, 22.5, 30.5, 28.9, 32.1, 17.4, 15.9, 18.8], 
      [15, "Hawaii", "HI", 11.4, 0.8, 38.1, 0.2, 69592, 1456, 8.1, 7.1, 9, 22.1, 20.7, 23.5, 14.1, 13, 15.3], 
      [16, "Idaho", "ID", 14.8, 0.7, 35.9, 0.2, 47861, 1275, 16.5, 15, 18.1, 28.9, 27.1, 30.8, 15.9, 14.4, 17.4], 
      [17, "Illinois", "IL", 14.4, 0.3, 37.5, 0.2, 57444, 429, 11.9, 10.5, 13.3, 29.3, 27.6, 31.1, 16.5, 15.1, 18], 
      [18, "Indiana", "IN", 15.2, 0.4, 37.4, 0.2, 49446, 487, 14.8, 13.8, 15.8, 32.7, 31.5, 33.9, 22.9, 21.8, 24.1], 
      [19, "Iowa", "IA", 12.2, 0.5, 38.2, 0.1, 53712, 761, 7.7, 6.8, 8.6, 30.9, 29.6, 32.3, 18.5, 17.3, 19.7], 
      [20, "Kansas", "KS", 13.6, 0.5, 36.2, 0.1, 52504, 706, 14.5, 13.7, 15.3, 31.3, 30.3, 32.2, 18.1, 17.2, 18.9], 
      [21, "Kentucky", "KY", 19.1, 0.5, 38.5, 0.2, 42958, 697, 10, 8.8, 11.1, 31.6, 30.2, 33.1, 26.2, 24.7, 27.7], 
      [22, "Louisiana", "LA", 19.8, 0.5, 36.1, 0.1, 44555, 738, 18.7, 17.4, 20, 34.9, 33.4, 36.4, 24, 22.6, 25.4], 
      [23, "Maine", "ME", 14.1, 0.7, 44.1, 0.2, 49462, 1112, 11, 10, 12, 28.2, 26.9, 29.5, 19.3, 18.1, 20.5], 
      [24, "Maryland", "MD", 10.1, 0.4, 38.3, 0.1, 73971, 867, 9.2, 8, 10.4, 29.6, 28.1, 31.1, 14.6, 13.4, 15.9], 
      [25, "Massachusetts", "MA", 11.6, 0.3, 39.4, 0.2, 69160, 957, 4.6, 4, 5.2, 23.3, 22.3, 24.4, 14.7, 13.7, 15.7], 
      [26, "Michigan", "MI", 16.2, 0.3, 39.6, 0.1, 49847, 385, 10.3, 9.3, 11.2, 30.7, 29.4, 32, 21.2, 20, 22.5], 
      [27, "Minnesota", "MN", 11.5, 0.4, 37.8, 0.1, 61481, 471, 7.3, 6.7, 7.9, 27.6, 26.8, 28.5, 16.3, 15.6, 17], 
      [28, "Mississippi", "MS", 21.5, 0.6, 36.7, 0.2, 39680, 773, 18.8, 17, 20.7, 35.5, 33.4, 37.6, 23, 21, 24.9], 
      [29, "Missouri", "MO", 15.5, 0.4, 38.5, 0.1, 48363, 567, 12.9, 11.6, 14.3, 30.2, 28.6, 31.9, 20.6, 19.2, 22.1], 
      [30, "Montana", "MT", 15.4, 0.8, 39.6, 0.3, 46328, 1217, 12.9, 11.6, 14.1, 26.4, 24.9, 27.9, 19.9, 18.5, 21.4], 
      [31, "Nebraska", "NE", 12.4, 0.5, 36.2, 0.2, 52686, 688, 12.4, 11.5, 13.2, 30.2, 29.2, 31.2, 17.3, 16.5, 18.2], 
      [32, "Nevada", "NV", 15.2, 0.7, 37.4, 0.2, 51450, 683, 17.1, 15, 19.3, 27.7, 25.3, 30.1, 17, 15, 19], 
      [33, "New Hampshire", "NH", 9.2, 0.6, 42.5, 0.3, 66532, 1297, 11.4, 10.1, 12.7, 27.4, 25.8, 29.1, 17.5, 16, 19], 
      [34, "New Jersey", "NJ", 11.1, 0.3, 39.4, 0.2, 71919, 438, 12.5, 11.5, 13.4, 26.9, 25.7, 28.1, 15.1, 14.1, 16.1], 
      [35, "New Mexico", "NM", 21.3, 0.9, 37.2, 0.2, 44803, 849, 15.4, 14.1, 16.8, 28.4, 26.9, 30, 19.2, 17.7, 20.6], 
      [36, "New York", "NY", 15.9, 0.3, 38.2, 0.1, 58878, 393, 12.3, 11.1, 13.4, 27, 25.6, 28.4, 14.4, 13.3, 15.5], 
      [37, "North Carolina", "NC", 17.2, 0.3, 38.3, 0.1, 46556, 381, 16.1, 15.1, 17.2, 29.7, 28.4, 31, 19.1, 17.9, 20.3], 
      [38, "North Dakota", "ND", 11.5, 0.9, 35.1, 0.2, 59029, 1681, 8.8, 7.6, 10, 32.2, 30.5, 33.9, 19.9, 18.4, 21.5], 
      [39, "Ohio", "OH", 15.8, 0.3, 39.4, 0.1, 49308, 363, 10.2, 9.2, 11.3, 32.6, 31.2, 34.1, 21, 19.7, 22.3], 
      [40, "Oklahoma", "OK", 16.6, 0.4, 36.2, 0.2, 47529, 454, 13.9, 12.9, 15, 33, 31.6, 34.3, 21.1, 19.9, 22.3], 
      [41, "Oregon", "OR", 16.6, 0.5, 39.3, 0.2, 51075, 490, 11, 9.7, 12.4, 27.9, 26.2, 29.6, 17, 15.5, 18.4], 
      [42, "Pennsylvania", "PA", 13.6, 0.3, 40.7, 0.1, 53234, 420, 10.1, 9.2, 11.1, 30.2, 28.9, 31.4, 19.9, 18.8, 21.1], 
      [44, "Rhode Island", "RI", 14.3, 0.9, 39.8, 0.3, 54891, 1488, 8, 6.8, 9.2, 27, 25.4, 28.6, 16.3, 14.8, 17.7], 
      [45, "South Carolina", "SC", 18, 0.5, 38.8, 0.1, 45238, 507, 17.1, 16, 18.2, 32.1, 30.9, 33.3, 21.5, 20.4, 22.7], 
      [46, "South Dakota", "SD", 14.2, 0.7, 36.6, 0.3, 50979, 1027, 9.9, 8.4, 11.4, 29.8, 27.9, 31.8, 18.6, 16.9, 20.2], 
      [47, "Tennessee", "TN", 18.3, 0.4, 38.6, 0.1, 44361, 561, 14.2, 12.6, 15.9, 31.2, 29.3, 33.1, 24.2, 22.3, 26.1], 
      [48, "Texas", "TX", 17.2, 0.2, 34.3, 0.1, 53035, 377, 24.9, 23.7, 26.1, 31.9, 30.6, 33.3, 14.5, 13.6, 15.5], 
      [49, "Utah", "UT", 11.7, 0.6, 30.5, 0.1, 60922, 658, 13.9, 13.2, 14.6, 25.7, 24.9, 26.6, 9.7, 9, 10.3], 
      [50, "Vermont", "VT", 12.2, 0.8, 42.8, 0.3, 54166, 1724, 6.7, 5.9, 7.5, 24.8, 23.5, 26.1, 16.4, 15.2, 17.6], 
      [51, "Virginia", "VA", 11.8, 0.3, 37.7, 0.1, 64902, 624, 13.1, 12, 14.1, 28.5, 27.2, 29.7, 19.5, 18.4, 20.7], 
      [53, "Washington", "WA", 13.2, 0.4, 37.5, 0.1, 61366, 485, 10.7, 9.7, 11.8, 27.3, 26, 28.5, 15.3, 14.3, 16.4], 
      [54, "West Virginia", "WV", 18.3, 0.7, 41.9, 0.2, 41059, 651, 10.1, 9.1, 11.2, 35.7, 34.2, 37.2, 26.7, 25.2, 28.1], 
      [55, "Wisconsin", "WI", 13.2, 0.4, 39.2, 0.2, 52622, 433, 8.5, 7.4, 9.7, 31.2, 29.6, 32.8, 17.4, 16, 18.7], 
      [56, "Wyoming", "WY", 11.2, 0.9, 36.6, 0.4, 57055, 1983, 15.1, 13.3, 16.9, 29.5, 27.4, 31.5, 19.5, 17.6, 21.4]
    ]
  }

  return src.rows.map(row => {
    return row.reduce((result, field, index) => {
      result[src.headers[index]] = field;
      return result
    }, {});
  });
}
```

```css
.aText {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  fill: #000;
  transition: fill 0.3s ease-out;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.inactive {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  fill: #c9c9c9;
  transition: fill 0.3s ease-out;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.inactive:hover {
  fill: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* font size dependent on radius, see app.js */
.stateText {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: #fff;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.stateCircle {
  fill: #89bdd3;
  stroke: #e3e3e3;
}

.stateCircleTrans {
  fill: #89bdd3;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #e3e3e3;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.d3-tip {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
/*.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  offset: 0 -30;
} */

.regression {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-dasharray: 10,5;
}

.equation {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Mobile Rules */
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
  .stateText {
    display: none;
  }

  .aText {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .aText {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <h1>D3Times</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-9">
        <div id="scatter">
          <!-- We append our chart here. -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-9">
        <div class="article">
          <p id="equation"></p>
          <h2 id="healthHeader">Correlations Discovered Between Health Risks and Age, Income</h2>
          <p id="healthCommentary">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor
            quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean
            ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the issue; I'm just curious why does this works? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I got the answer from the link @Robin Mackenzie provided. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @SeanGalloway - if it works for you, you can tick the answer.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie thanks for referencing my comment and for adding the working example. I added another answer to elaborate on the difference between a selection object and a transition object in D3, and to explain why it is only an issue in the first render.